# Import data from a CSV file from Angular

Tags: angularjs, csv, playframework

I want to import data from a csv file and insert them in MongoDB. So firstly I get the data from the csv file and I display my data in the console using AngularJS.

Now I want to pass my data (from AngularJS) to a play controller where I want to parse data and then insert it in my database.

So I defined this route:

```
POST    /input/:data        controllers.InputController.showinput(data)
```

Where data is the data that I get from AngularJS and InputController is my controller.

I am currently blocked, I don't know if I'm on the right track or not and also there is any example to parse my data in controller?

Comment: Where are you stuck on except "I don't know if I'm on the right track?"  There are several things going on here:  1) Reading the file, 2) Parsing a CSV, 3) Returning data to the front-end, 4) Writing to database.  Any one of these steps can be super simple to do, or really involved.  It all depends on context.  So exactly, what is your question?

Comment: Actually I get data from the file using angular but when i try to send data to my controller using the route I get this message: 414 (Request-URI Too Long) because the file is big so I need another solution

Comment: So your issue has nothing to do with MongoDB for now, you have to figure out how to send large data over HTTP using Angular, without putting everything in the request URI/query string, as this can possibly hit the limit about that (contrary to POSTing or PUTing).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting data from csv file, you can first insert csv file in `mongoDB` by using the `monngoImport` command. Then you can access data from csv file using angularjs.